# Which Join is needed for this query in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, join, pagination

I need to return paginated results i.e the second five records from a table called properties. This works alone with this query:

```
SELECT  
    Property_ID, 
    Property_Type, 
    Address_Line, 
    Area, 
    Postcode, 
    Weekly_Rate 
FROM
    dbo.Properties 
WHERE   
    Area LIKE '%" + value + "%' 
ORDER BY 
    Property_ID 
    OFFSET " + (start*end) + " ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT " + end + " ROWS ONLY"
```

The above code is written with C# added.

But I also need the first Image ID from the Images table that references each record returned in the paginated subset.

I tried a FULL OUTER JOIN and it didn't return what was expected, maybe because there is more than one image per property.

Any solutions to this would be great!

Thanks

This seems to nearly work but it's returning an error:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Properties.Property_ID, Property_Type, dbo.Images_Table.[URL]
FROM 
    dbo.Properties p 
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 i.*
     FROM dbo.Images_Table i
     WHERE i.Property_ID = p.Property_ID
     ORDER BY i.Image_ID) i
WHERE 
    p.Area LIKE '%po%' 
ORDER BY 
    p.Property_ID 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

This is the error returned :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.Properties.Property_ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.Images_Table.URL" could not be bound.

Comment: What is the relation between the `Properties` table and the `Images` table? Table schemas would be good to see.

Comment: Property_ID is a foreign key in the Images table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT . . . , i.??
FROM dbo.Properties p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 i.*
      FROM images i
      WHERE i.Property_ID = p.Property_ID
      ORDER BY i.Image_ID
     ) i
WHERE p.Area LIKE '%" + value + "%' 
ORDER BY p.Property_ID 
OFFSET " + (start*end) + " ROWS 
FETCH NEXT " + end + " ROWS ONLY";
```

This is a bit speculative on how you are ordering the images.  You also need to fill in the columns you want from the `images` table.

Comment: I wrote this in sql-server:

Comment: SELECT dbo.Properties.Property_ID, Property_Type, dbo.Images_Table.[URL]
FROM dbo.Properties p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 i.*
      FROM dbo.Images_Table i
      WHERE i.Property_ID = p.Property_ID
      ORDER BY i.Image_ID
     ) i
WHERE p.Area LIKE '%po%' 
ORDER BY p.Property_ID 
OFFSET " + (start*end) + " ROWS 
FETCH NEXT " + end + " ROWS ONLY

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Properties.Property_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Images_Table.URL" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name ' + end + '.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name ' + (start*end) + '.

Comment: what am I missing sorry?

Comment: @Kieran . . . I'm not sure.  The query in your answer looks pretty similar to the query in this answer -- once parameters are inserted.